# Weird character encoded characters (â€™) appearing from a feed

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, character-encoding

I've got a question regarding an XML feed and XSL transformation I'm doing. In a few parts of the outputted feed on an HTML page, I get weird characters (such as â€™) appearing on the page.

[image: Bad characters]

On another site (that I don't own) that's using the same feed, it isn't getting these characters.

[image: No bad characters]

Here's the code I'm using to grab and return the transformed content:

```
string xmlUrl = "http://feedurl.com/feed.xml";
string xmlData = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(xmlUrl);
string xslUrl = "http://feedurl.com/transform.xsl";
XsltArgumentList xslArgs = new XsltArgumentList();
xslArgs.AddParam("type", "", "specifictype");
string resultText = Utils.XslTransform(xmlData, xslUrl, xslArgs);
return resultText;
```

And my `Utils.XslTransform` function looks like this:

```
static public string XslTransform(string data, string xslurl)
{
    TextReader textReader = new StringReader(data);
    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore;
    XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(textReader, settings);
    XmlReader xslReader = new XmlTextReader(Uri.UnescapeDataString(xslurl));
    XslCompiledTransform myXslT = new XslCompiledTransform();
    myXslT.Load(xslReader);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    using (TextWriter tw = new StringWriter(sb))
    {
        myXslT.Transform(xmlReader, new XsltArgumentList(), tw);
    }

    string transformedData = sb.ToString();
    return transformedData;
}
```

I'm not extremely knowledgeable with character encoding issues and I've been trying to nip this in the bud for a bit of time and could use any suggestions possible. I'm not sure if there's something I need to change with how the WebClient downloads the file or something going weird in the XslTransform.

Thanks!

Comment: Consider to pass the URLs to XslCompiledTransform, not the string you download with WebClient.

Comment: Where's the first point you see the issue? Is it in `xmlData`? If it is, then the issue is most likely the encoding `WebClient` is using.

Answer (score 0):

Give [HtmlEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz(v=vs.110).aspx) a try. So in this case you would reference System.Web and then make this change (just call the HtmlEncode function on the last line):

```
string xmlUrl = "http://feedurl.com/feed.xml";
string xmlData = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(xmlUrl);
string xslUrl = "http://feedurl.com/transform.xsl";
XsltArgumentList xslArgs = new XsltArgumentList();
xslArgs.AddParam("type", "", "specifictype");
string resultText = Utils.XslTransform(xmlData, xslUrl, xslArgs);
return HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(resultText);
```

Comment: Added the `HtmlDecode` line in, and nothing changed. Still seeing the odd characters.

Comment: Oops, I might have had the direction backwards. You probably need to switch encoding TO html-entities instead of FROM. Sorry about that... will edit answer.

Comment: That just ended up turning the HTML into encoded entities, &lt; and &gt; and all that jazz.

Answer (score 0):

The character â is a marker of multibyte sequence (â€™) of UTF-8-encoded text when it's represented as ASCII. So, I guess, you generate an HTML file in UTF-8, while browser interprets it otherwise. I see 2 ways to fix it:

1. The simplest solution would be to update the XSLT to include the HTML meta tag that will hint the correct encoding to browser: `<meta charset="UTF-8">`.
2. If your transform already defines a different encoding in meta tag and you'd like to keep it, this encoding needs to be specified in the function that saves XML as file. I assume this function took ASCII by default in your example. If your XSLT was configured to generate XML files directly to disk, you could adjust it with XSLT instruction `<xsl:output encoding="ASCII"/>`.

Comment: I've added the meta charset to the page and that didn't end up helping. I'll have to look into #2 a little more.

Comment: I feel that the root of the issue is there. Curious to know if it works out. If the function that writes to disk doesn't receive encoding it might be necessary to recode the string before saving.

Comment: Got stuck on another project, now I'm back to this. The XSL already had an output encoding UTF-8 in there, but even changing it to ASCII did nothing for me.

Comment: Did you mean <xsl:output> instruction? It could have effect if you ran the conversion from command line and the processor serialized the final XML file to disk itself (e.g. when you run Saxon from the command line).

Comment: In your case, the result of transform is returned as string in C# and I surmise that encoding is lost in that part of code or when you save this string to disk. Can you please try to make one more change: update the myXslT.Transform() call to use XmlWriter as third parameter. When you create a new XMLWriter you can configure it with XmlWriterSettings that contains an Encoding field which you can set to the desired value: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

To use `WebClient.DownloadString` you have to know what the encoding the server is going use and tell the WebClient *in advance.* It's a bit of a Catch-22.

But, there is no need to do that. Use `WebClient.DownloadData` or `WebClient.OpenReader` and let an XML library figure out which encoding to use.

```
using (var web = new WebClient())
using (var stream = web.OpenRead("http://unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml"))
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream, new XmlReaderSettings { DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse }))
{
    reader.MoveToContent();
    //… use reader as you will, including var doc = XDocument.ReadFrom(reader);
}
```